# add extra parameter in default hook in wordpress

Tags: hooks, buddypress

The default hook is bp_activity_posted_update, Its have three default parameters as "$content, $user_id, $activity_id". Now need to add extra parameter as "$post_id", How can achieve this.

```
function bp_add_visibility_to_activity( $content, $user_id, $activity_id ) {

}

add_action( 'bp_activity_posted_update', 'bp_add_visibility_to_activity', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to add this parameter, you can use `global $post;`

```
function bp_add_visibility_to_activity( $content, $user_id, $activity_id ) {
    global $post;

    $post_id = $post->ID;
    // do stuff
}

add_action( 'bp_activity_posted_update', 'bp_add_visibility_to_activity', 10, 3 );
```

Note that `$post->ID` will return null if your are not in a post or page, so you maybe need to check the post_id value before any treatment, to avoid error or notice.

Hope it helps !

Comment: No I could not got.